# Java export running jar w/ project

Tags: java, eclipse, export-to-excel, xlsx

So, I've added a git repo to my project ([sjxlsx](https://github.com/davidpelfree/sjxlsx)). I've then right-clicked the repo and imported into the package explorer. I then went to Project->Build path in order to make sure it's on "Required projects on the build path".

When I debug on Eclipse, works just fine.

I'm now trying to export as a running jar and when I execute it outside of Eclipse, it somehow is giving an error (empty.xlsx not found). That is, because in the XLSXWriterSupport, the open method is fetching this empty.xlsx file. On debug, it's working as expected but on converting to a running jar, it's giving me this error.

This is due to this 'empty.xlsx' file being on the resources of the other project. How can I solve this?

> https://github.com/davidpelfree/sjxlsx/blob/master/src/main/java/com/incesoft/tools/excel/support/XLSXWriterSupport.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because a *resource* on the class path is **not** a *File* on the file system. 
Here it is packed in a jar (zip format).

The wrong code:

```
if (getClass().getResource("/empty.xlsx") == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("no empty.xlsx found in classpath");
    }
    workbook = new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(new File(getClass().getResource("/empty.xlsx").getFile()));
```

As SimpleXLSXWorkbook has only a File constructor (AFAIK), you need to create a temporary file.

```
Path tempPath = Files.createTempFile("sjxlsx-", ".xlsx");
Files.copy(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/empty.xlsx"), tempPath);
workbook = new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(tempPath.toFile());
```

Better have some provision to delete temp files, for instance creating them in a specific directory, see [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-).

Comment: I worked around a similar solution but this approach works aswell, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the Eclipse Project build path configured to use absolute library references. When you try to run your runnable jar, the jvm cannot find the required dependencies.

### Edit:

If you want to export your software as a RUNNABLE jar file, then the jar must contain a MANIFEST file which specifies the dependencies and main class. Example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.example.Main
Class-Path: lib1.jar lib2.jar
```

(assuming your main class is com.example.Main)
In order to run your runnable jar file, place lib1 and lib2 on the same directory as your runnable jar and run:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

Otherwise you could just compile your main class and run it like this (assuming lib1 and lib2 are copied into a lib/ dir on your main class root path):

```
java -cp '.:/libs/*.jar' com.example.Main
```

You could also use a dependency manager tool such as maven and configure your build to create an "uberJar":https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html
uberJars contain all your software dependencies in one heavy runnable jar file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll check this in the morning, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: The option `-cp` doesn't work when using `-jar`. When using `-jar`, the class path must be defined by the jar manifest.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that is true. -cp option does not work with -jar. I'm sorry